# How many consecutive descending numbers in my number?

Tags: code-golf

2019 has come and probably everyone has noticed the peculiarity of this number: it's in fact composed by two sub-numbers (20 and 19) representing a sequence of consecutive descending numbers.

#### Challenge

Given a number `x`, return the length of the maximum sequence of consecutive, descending numbers that can be formed by taking sub-numbers of `x`.

Notes :

- sub-numbers cannot contain leading zeros (e.g. `1009` cannot be split into `10`,`09`)
- consecutive and descending means that a number in the sequence must be equal to the previous number -1, or \$n_{i+1} = n_{i}-1\$ (e.g. `52` cannot be split into `5,2` because `5` and `2` are not consecutive, `2 ≠ 5 - 1`)
- the sequence must be obtained by using the full number, e.g. in `7321` you can't discard `7` and get the sequence `3`,`2`,`1`
- only one sequence can be obtained from the number, e.g. `3211098` cannot be split into two sequences `3`,`2`,`1` and `10`,`9`,`8`

#### Input

- An integer number (`>= 0`) : can be a number, or a string, or list of digits

#### Output

- A single integer given the maximum number of decreasing sub-numbers (note that the lower-bound of this number is `1`, i.e. a number is composed by itself in a descending sequence of length one)

#### Examples :

```
2019         --> 20,19           --> output : 2
201200199198 --> 201,200,199,198 --> output : 4
3246         --> 3246            --> output : 1
87654        --> 8,7,6,5,4       --> output : 5
123456       --> 123456          --> output : 1
1009998      --> 100,99,98       --> output : 3
100908       --> 100908          --> output : 1
1110987      --> 11,10,9,8,7     --> output : 5
210          --> 2,1,0           --> output : 3
1            --> 1               --> output : 1
0            --> 0               --> output : 1
312          --> 312             --> output : 1
191          --> 191             --> output : 1
```

#### General rules:

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.
  Don't let code-golf languages discourage you from posting answers with non-codegolfing languages. Try to come up with an as short as possible answer for 'any' programming language.
- [Standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) for your answer with [default I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/), so you are allowed to use STDIN/STDOUT, functions/method with the proper parameters and return-type, full programs. Your call.
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- If possible, please add a link with a test for your code (i.e. [TIO](https://tio.run/#)).
- Also, adding an explanation for your answer is highly recommended.

Comment: Migrated from sandbox : https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/17247#17247

Comment: Is the test case `210 -> 2,1,0` wrong (same with `0 -> 0`)? The tasks says "*sub-numbers cannot contain leading zeros*", is zero a special case?

Comment: @BMO: well, here the topic is kinda phylosofical... :D to me, 0 is a number with no (useless) leading zero, so yes zero is a special case

Comment: would you call these... _condescending_ numbers? xD sorry that was like not even funny

Comment: Sorry, deleted my comment in which I asked about `212019`. Seems I didn't read all the rules.

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), 56 bytes

A port of [ArBo's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/178753/58563) is significantly shorter. However, it fails on some test cases because of too much recursion.

```javascript
f=(n,a=0,c=0,s)=>a<0?f(n,a-~c):n==s?c:f(n,--a,c+1,[s]+a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jdDBisIwEAbg@z5FyKnBic5UazPF6IOIh5C1y4o0YqpHX71W0F3b6rI/5DKEj59/584u@uP3odZV@Nw2TWmTCpxF8O2Lyi7dAlfl7aYvXhWVtXHli9tBawd@RLCOm5FTjQ9VDPvteB@@kjKRKRJLcY9SYjIRKQKx@I3WSxFO9eFUi0KkHz3A5PNsJjuAgRzmkMHsFZD1AUJkZiOfgPYEzMDmFTAdAETIJu8ABNQS0Db5R4OU8GeCxwZAgO82GDaQT1/vDUQ3HYD6AA4B/BNorg)

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 66 bytes

Takes input as a string.

```javascript
f=(s,n=x='',o=p=n,i=0)=>s[i++]?o==s?i:f(s,--n,o+n,i):f(s,p+s[x++])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZLdboJAEEbv@xQbboQw1Jnlb9dk9UFML4yVhsawpGDj29OpSisLGp2ECz4mJ@fb5XPzvWm2X2XdRpV933VdYfwGKnM0sxlYU5sKSoOBWTbrMgzfVtaYZlUuCl6KogpsyN@D02sdNusjrwTd1laN3e9e9/bDL3xPImlPXCYIxHwuJAJp8T9RtBT20NaHViyEfBkDJDJEk1ZeDyDgjCmaHzUEJC4glknmGPxG4pYBuQCVZ2niDQAKcsgghWQKkLoAknGS9g5nwDl61IAQteb61wDuz/W5/QQgngKgGhqcoocNiFCrfGBAQOwAfBYPnIEk/LuE/j8AArx1C@MK3tXqxUAM534FHAPwKUBM0q3A0RMA0uQCOLoD6H4A)

#### Commented

```javascript
f = (               // f = recursive function taking:
  s,                //   s = input number, as a string
  n =               //   n = counter
  x = '',           //   x = position of the next digit to be added to p
  o = p = n,        //   o = generated output; p = prefix
  i = 0             //   i = number of consecutive descending numbers
) =>                //
  s[i++] ?          // increment i; if s[i] was defined:
    o == s ?        //   if o is matching s:
      i             //     stop recursion and return i
    :               //   else:
      f(            //     do a recursive call with:
        s,          //       s unchanged
        --n,        //       n - 1
        o + n,      //       (n - 1) appended to o
        i           //       i unchanged (but it was incremented above)
      )             //     end of recursive call
  :                 // else:
    f(              //   this is a dead end; try again with one more digit in the prefix:
      s,            //     s unchanged
      p + s[x++]    //     increment x and append the next digit to p
    )               //   end of recursive call
```

Comment: [54 bytes](https://tio.run/##jdDBisIwEAbgu08RcmpwojNdazOF6IPIHkLWios0sqke99W7WXBd26o4kMtM@Pj5P93ZRf@1P7a6CR/brqtt1oCzCD69qOyqsTaufeXWdTpo7cBPCTbxfepU9bty@turzocmhsN2dgi7rM5kjsRSXEYpMZ@LHIFY/I/WKxFO7fHUikrkkwFgymWxkD3AQAlLKGBxDyiGACEys5E3QFoBM7C5B7yNACJkU/YAAkoEpCQvJMgJrxX8dQAE@KiDcQJ58/WSQPSnB9AQwDGAT4HuBw) by implementing the changes to my code

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>15</s>  9 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

Bugfix thanks to Dennis

```
ŻṚẆDfŒṖẈṀ
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9qZWxsef//xbvhuZrhuoZEZsWS4bmW4bqI4bmA////MjEw)** (even `321` takes half a minute since the code is at least \$O(N^2)\$)

#### How?

```
ŻṚẆDfŒṖẈṀ - Link: integer, n
Ż         - [0..n]
 Ṛ        - reverse
  Ẇ       - all contiguous slices (of implicit range(n)) = [[n],...,[2],[1],[0],[n,n-1],...,[2,1],[1,0],...,[n,n-1,n-2,...,2,1,0]]
   D      - to decimal (vectorises)
     ŒṖ   - partitions of (implicit decimal digits of) n
    f     - filter discard from left if in right
       Ẉ  - length of each
        Ṁ - maximum
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>43 41</s> 40 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to nwellnhof*

```perl6
{/(<-[0]>.*?|0)+<?{[==] 1..*Z+$0}>/;+$0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZBNboMwEEb3PsXIqioIgzNjft0Gco9SFl0EKRJtUCCLiObs1E1KCy31xvKbN5/HbnbHOh5ez3BfQQZDv3Y2fkFlrlbbd3K9zbYvsqwEVmr15N3RJV8/fm5DdTiCU@/fdq2b56pt6n3nSN/PpQu9AGhfzuApG4TyuZNYOdeDixIkqkKX4jJoYgPjsp2gCSfkxg6nrjl18ABaWF@T7TFs0i@f0RLbZHBk334oAh3Gs6wZ@J3PIk3iKJzWUkwwxgjDJT8SrIMwiie1Gfibz0TG2DF/fDu7HX1Ecz@4@jStzcBCPjOZNJn4jGxvQPuOpfk10@0bkZH@@5bgAw)

Regex based solution. I'm trying to come up with a better way to match from a descending list instead, but Perl 6 doesn't do partitions well

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{                                        }  # Anonymous code block
 /                                /;        # Match in the input
   <-[0]>.*?      # Non-greedy number not starting with 0
            |0    # Or 0
  (           )+  # Repeatedly for the rest of the number
                <?{             }>  # Where
                        1..*Z+$0       # Each matched number plus the ascending numbers
                                       # For example 1,2,3 Z+ 9,8,7 is 10,10,10
                   [==]                # Are all equal
                                    +$0  # Return the length of the list
```

Comment: [40 bytes](https://tio.run/##dZBNboMwEEb3PsXIqioIgzNjft0Gco9SFl0EKRJtUCCLiObs1E1KCy31xvKbN5/HbnbHOh5ez3BfQQZDv3Y2fkFlrlbbd3K9zbYvsqwEVmr15N3RJV8/fm5DdTiCU@/fdq2b56pt6n3nSN/PpQu9AGhfzuApG4TyuZNYOdeDixIkqkKX4jJoYgPjsp2gCSfkxg6nrjl18ABaWF@T7TFs0i@f0RLbZHBk334oAh3Gs6wZ@J3PIk3iKJzWUkwwxgjDJT8SrIMwiie1Gfibz0TG2DF/fDu7HX1Ecz@4@jStzcBCPjOZNJn4jGxvQPuOpfk10@0bkZH@@5bgAw "Perl 6 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>232</strike> <strike>228</strike> <strike>187</strike> <strike>181</strike> <strike>180</strike> <strike>150</strike> 149 bytes

-1 thanks to @[Jonathan Frech](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/73111/jonathan-frech)

```python
e=enumerate
t=int
h=lambda n,s=1:max([1]+[i-len(n[j:])and h(n[j:],s+1)or s+1for j,_ in e(n)for i,_ in e(n[:j],1)if(t(n[:j])-t(n[j:j+i])==1)*t(n[0])])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVLLboMwELzzFauecONUGEgCSD70UPUjCEIOOAUEBoFpElX9dmockiak9WU9szPrx25zklktnGHglIu@4i2T3JA0F9LIaMmqXcpA4I6SoGJHMyTRIsyXJRemCIsgQkykkJ33uFsQVLegwl6FAseQC@CmQCPMrzAMiggTlO9NeQZoKXWFYpFHiFKCnkdsRShCQ1Yf4oqJU5zUouNJL/NP3gGFDAxQy0j5HljX8VbGh1xmcdOqm5sfSiUw8GPDE8lTDCyRPStRoE1n/TULlE55DE9b8T56g1H39b0Vb5Mo0OhVy4Ip9/SiHlax/48z9PUk76Q5Hc2PrGpK/YJQE@MybQy2RXyEfylXU7alaJ/43m2KYHBsd31LrTB4m/XKncmI7birO6GjSMvy/YeKI2t5s5qEEMv3NrMCNrHm5hme5x1izx3@xRMZOowjcvm/WM3hjrdYzUvTywnp4Zl@L7jWemz9rQc/lvxznsxOtndGhFTvzn0bfgA)

Initial ungolfed code:

```python
def count_consecutives(left, right, so_far=1):
    for i,_ in enumerate(left, start=1):
        left_part_of_right, right_part_of_right = right[:i], right[i:]
        if (int(left) - int(left_part_of_right)) == 1:
            if i == len(right):
                return so_far + 1
            return count_consecutives(left_part_of_right, right_part_of_right, so_far + 1)
    return so_far

def how_many_consecutives(n):
    for i, _ in enumerate(n):
        left, right = n[:i], n[i:]
        for j, _ in enumerate(left, start=1):            
            left_part_of_right = right[:j]
            if int(left) - int(left_part_of_right) == 1 and int(n[i]) > 0:     
                return count_consecutives(left, right)
    return 1
```

Comment: `s+1 for` can be `s+1for`, `(t(n[:j])-t(n[j:j+i])==1)*t(n[0])` can possibly be `t(n[:j])-t(n[j:j+i])==1>=t(n[0])`.

Comment: It seems that second suggestion doesn't work though it wouldn't bring anything because then you need space to separate expression from `if`.

Comment: True ... alternative [149](https://tio.run/##vVNRb4IwEH7nV1y2B2mspi26CRkmPiz7EYyQTurAQCW0bi7LfrsrBR3i9rq@XO@777v22rvqQ2c76R2PWVjw8iXlILEKKdZhLjUWoZD7UtRci6DkBzei8TjKJ4WQroy2QYy4TCFr91iNKdrVYMzGmC1OIJcgXIkaNz@7UbCNMUX5ZsIetJVux3mMJroNoQdiYRKjGB2z3XtScvmRrHdSifVe529CQQgZOGCWk4oNcKVErZP3XGdJVZtru6@GJTGIQyXWWqQY@FrveYECK2r55yiEYRfHcPMsnxpt0PA@v57lY0cKrLeytKCL3UxNYSX/@zjHXk8Lpd3uaHHgZVXYCiILNMtlGBihPsI/0MxCjBjYp/6iH6IYPDa760NzDIv7u/lsQKPMm80viJ4BCfH9q4wNShaDnJRS4i/uBwkYJUPxwB/GPcqGCv@kiR1rmhY5vV9iWu5F1Nj0S7XXnWebp3u94Jzr@uv7Gnyd8td@cpWuL4QImb9r/81xbv9/MoAtT9Mw6Y3IsjcZTlvuaFUUtsMUVM1jpNMROn4D).

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>78</s> <s>74</s> 73 bytes

```python
l=lambda n,a=0,c=0,s="":c*(n==s)or a and l(n,a-1,c+1,s+`a-1`)or l(n,a-~c)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYrRCgIhFETf9yvEJ20tNGqLwH9ZcxcS9Cpee9iXft1uBNHAwJyZKVt7ZDj2kEqujeGGA/mAa6urf1YMGWJIoQmjSbJHG126L46BclYrT0bL@c3vBFiLMlfmmIOFRUGPvVF@NArHmeL8Gb/1y8teaoBGzDWXww/MP1wv0/nEZX8D)

<sub>-1 byte thanks to Arnauld</sub>

Takes input as a string. The program rather quickly runs into Python's recursion depth limit, but it can finish most of the test cases.

#### How it works

```python
l=lambda n,                              # The input number, in the form of a string
         a=0,                            # The program will attempt to reconstruct n by
                                         #  building a string by pasting decreasing
                                         #  numbers, stored in a, after each other.
         c=0,                            # A counter of the amount of numbers
         s="":                           # The current constructed string
              c*(n==s)                   # Return the counter if s matches n
              or                         # Else
              a and l(n,a-1,c+1,s+`a-1`) # If a is not yet zero, paste a-1 after s
              or                         # Else
              l(n,a-~c)                  # Start again, from one higher than last time
```

Comment: Nice answer! `a+c+1` can be shortened to `a-~c`.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ÝRŒʒJQ}€gà
```

Extremely slow, so the TIO below only works for test cases below 750..

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8Nygo5NOTfIKrH3UtCb98IL//w0NLAE).

**Explanation:**

```python
Ý           # Create a list in the range [0, (implicit) input]
            #  i.e. 109 → [0,1,2,...,107,108,109]
 R          # Reverse it
            #  i.e. [0,1,2,...,107,108,109] → [109,108,107,...,2,1,0]
  Œ         # Get all possible sublists of this list
            #  i.e. [109,108,107,...,2,1,0]
            #   → [[109],[109,108],[109,108,107],...,[2,1,0],[1],[1,0],[0]]
   ʒ  }     # Filter it by:
    J       #  Where the sublist joined together
            #   i.e. [10,9] → "109"
            #   i.e. [109,108,107] → "109108107"
     Q      #  Are equal to the (implicit) input
            #   i.e. 109 and "109" → 1 (truthy)
            #   i.e. 109 and "109108107" → 0 (falsey)
       €g   # After filtering, take the length of each remaining inner list
            #  i.e. [[109],[[10,9]] → [1,2]
         à  # And only leave the maximum length (which is output implicitly)
            #  i.e. [1,2] → 2
```

Comment: Code golf - where adding 1 byte to your program to go from `n!` to `n lg n` just isn't worth it.

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, 16 bytes

```
lef!.EhM.+vMT./z
```

Try it online [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=lef%21.EhM.%2BvMT.%2Fz&input=2019&debug=0), or verify all the test cases at once [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=lef%21.EhM.%2BvMT.%2Fz&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=2019%0A201200199198%0A3246%0A87654%0A123456%0A1009998%0A100908%0A1110987%0A210&debug=0).

```
lef!.EhM.+vMT./z   Implicit: z=input as string
             ./z   Get all divisions of z into disjoint substrings
  f                Filter the above, as T, keeping those where the following is truthy:
          vMT        Parse each substring as an int
        .+           Get difference between each pair
      hM             Increment each
   !.E               Are all elements 0? { NOT(ANY(...)) }
 e                 Take the last element of the filtered divisions
                     Divisions are generated with fewest substrings first, so last remaining division is also the longest
l                  Length of the above, implicit print
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
ŒṖḌ’Dɗ\ƑƇẈṀ
```

Byte for byte, no match for the other Jelly solution, but this one should be roughly \$O\left(n^{0.3}\right)\$.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opIc7pz3c0fOoYabLyekxxyYea3@4q@Phzob/R/coHG5/1LRGwf3/fyMDQ0sdBSBpZABkWRpaWugoGBuZmOkoWJibmZroKBgaGZuYArmGBgaWliBZEMMARBsaGlhamAM1GxoAeToKBiCmMZBpaQgA)

#### How it works

```
ŒṖḌ’Dɗ\ƑƇẈṀ  Main link. Argument: n (integer)

ŒṖ           Yield all partitions of n's digit list in base 10.
        Ƈ    Comb; keep only partitions for which the link to the left returns 1.
       Ƒ       Fixed; yield 1 if calling the link to the left returns its argument.
      \          Cumulatively reduce the partition by the link to the left.
     ɗ             Combine the three links to the left into a dyadic chain.
  Ḍ                  Undecimal; convert a digit list into an integer.
   ’                 Decrement the result.
    D                Decimal; convert the integer back to a digit list.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 27 bytes

```
ò pÊÔpÊqÊfl²i1Uì q"l?"¹ÌèÊÉ
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=8iBwytRwynHKZmyyaTFV7CBxImw/IrnM6MrJ&input=MjEyMDE=) or [Check most test cases](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=8iBwytRwynHKZmyyaTFV7CBxImw/IrnM6MrJ&input=WzIwMTkKMzI0Ngo4NzY1NAoxMjM0NTYKMTAwOTk5OAoxMDA5MDgKMTExMDk4NwoyMTAKMQowCjE5MQozMTJdCi1t)

This doesn't score well, but it uses a unique method and there might be room to golf it a lot more. It also performs well enough that all test cases other than `201200199198` avoid timing out.

Explanation:

```
ò                              #Get the range [0...input]
  pÊ                           #Add an "l" to the end
    Ô                          #Reverse it
     pÊ                        #Add an "l" to the end
       qÊ                      #Add an "l" between each number and turn to a string
         f            ¹        #Find the substrings that match this regex:
          l²                   # The string "ll"
            i1                 # With this inserted between the "l"s:
              Uì               #  All the digits of the input
                 q"l?"         #  With optional spaces between each one
                       Ì       #Get the last match
                        èÊ     #Count the number of "l"s
                          É    #Subtract 1
```

Comment: I think [this](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=O/Ig1CtKIGYsK1VzIG0rIiw/Iilt6Eogss7J&input=WzIwMTkKMzI0Ngo4NzY1NAoxMjM0NTYKMTAwOTk5OAoxMDA5MDgKMTExMDk4NwoyMTAKMQowCjE5MQozMTJdCi1t) works for 27.

Comment: [25 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=8iDUccpmbCtVcyBtKyJsPyIpruhsw7LOyQ==&input=WzIwMTkKMzI0Ngo4NzY1NAoxMjM0NTYKMTAwOTk5OAoxMDA5MDgKMTExMDk4NwoyMTAKMQowCjE5MQozMTJdCi1t)

Comment: @Shaggy both of those fail on input `21201` because they don't enforce that the sequence end aligns correctly (from my original version the "ends with a comma" line). [This](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=8iDUccpmbCtV7CBxImw/IiArJ2wgruhsw7LOyQ==&input=MjEyMDE=) or [this](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=8iDUccpmbCtVcyBtKyJsPyIgr0opruhsw7LOyQ==&input=MjEyMDE=) alternative works.

Comment: Ah, OK. In that case: [26 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=8iDUccpmbLJpMVXsIHEibD8iua7obMOyzsk=&input=MjEyMDE=)

Comment: @Shaggy That and the 28 byte solutions I had fail on `210` because there isn't a delimiter after 0. [Here](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=8iDUcMpxymZssmkxVewgcSJsPyK5ruhsw7LOyQ==&input=WzIwMTkKMzI0Ngo4NzY1NAoxMjM0NTYKMTAwOTk5OAoxMDA5MDgKMTExMDk4NwoyMTAKMQowCjE5MQozMTJdCi1t)'s a fixed 28 byte that works.

Comment: Ah, I see you figured out a fix - nicely done.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>302</s> <s>282</s> 271 bytes

-10 bytes thanks to the tip by @ElPedro.

Takes input as a string. Basically, it takes increasing larger slices of the number from the left, and sees if for that slice of the number a sequence can be formed using all the numbers.

```python
R=range
I=int
L=len
def g(n,m,t=1):
 for i in R(1,L(m)+1):
  if I(m)==I(n[:i])+1:
   if i==L(n):return-~t
   return g(n[i:],n[:i],t+1)
 return 1
def f(n):
 for i in R(L(n)):
  x=n[:i]
  for j in R(1,L(x)+1):
   if (I(x)==I(n[i:i+j])+1)*I(n[i]):return g(n[i:],x)
 return 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVHLbsIwELz7K1b04hRTeZ0AcST3HokTV5QDahNqVAxKXIkK0V9PvU6gxRfvzD5m1j59@4@jS/t@bdqt29WsNNZ5tjKftWPvdQM77sRBeINJwaA5tmDBOlhzFCt@SKaRBttAGZAxJXebwlaBJ5p4a8yKu6Roa//VutmPJ34ANHtji0rEHuHDMHZLYRRvqPNBlmZFybOJXSGi7P7P1PlmitR5GfBgyxZ2uidnyXOE1c3T3cb5n3zv686/bbu6AwMbpiRqAU@gKFIyII06JyZjqcoWFCHLl4t5RuGcoUqz@UijlFoP1WkEMh8TiFLny6FDoRwrhqQcrhTVWKwx3hVjtDH5o6XvPsPKpzb8HZ9crjB7hct18hIKD1vPqUaEx@x8G@MknP4X)

Comment: Since you are using `range` 3 times you can define `R=range` outside of both functions and then use `R(whatever)` instead of `range(whatever)` to save 4 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 26 bytes

```
Ｆ⊕ＬθＦ⊕Ｌθ⊞υ⭆κ⁻Ｉ…θιλＩ﹪⌕υθ⊕Ｌθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY27CgIxEEV7v2LKGYig24mlIAgGFvyCkMRNME7My9/PxsJS63POvdqprKMKvd9jBrywzvZpuVqDV8tLdZiICP7CuRWHTcCtZs@LVC98CJCeW8GTKhVlDAaTAE8kIIziuJmHWb/UtBDx7Nl8RtJwfhyNsPdptz/07Tus) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｆ⊕Ｌθ
```

Loop `i` from 0 to the length of the input.

```
Ｆ⊕Ｌθ
```

Loop `k` from 0 to the length of the input.

```
⊞υ⭆κ⁻Ｉ…θ⊕ιλ
```

Calculate the first `k` numbers in the descending sequence starting from the number given by the first `i` digits of the input, concatenate them, and accumulate each resulting string in the predefined empty list.

```
Ｉ﹪⌕υθ⊕Ｌθ
```

Find the position of the first matching copy of the input and reduce it modulo 1 more than the length of the input.

Example: For an input of `2019` the following strings are generated:

```
 0
 1  0
 2  0-1
 3  0-1-2
 4  0-1-2-3
 5  
 6  2
 7  21
 8  210
 9  210-1
10  
11  20
12  2019
13  201918
14  20191817
15  
16  201
17  201200
18  201200199
19  201200199198
20  
21  2019
22  20192018
23  201920182017
24  2019201820172016
```

`2019` is then found at index 12, which is reduced modulo 5 to give 2, the desired answer.

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, 87 bytes

```
maximum.map length.(0#)
a#(b:c)=[a:x|c==[]||b>0,x<-b#c,a==x!!0+1]++(10*a+b)#c
a#b=[[a]]
```

Input is a list of digits.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZBNDoIwEIX3nqKGDchIij@IxnoDT1C7mDYiRCDEn4QFZxenaEKNfcmk@eb1ddoc79dzWfaZOPUVtkX1rKIKG1ae68sjj3zuBRP0fL0zgZC4azsjhFRdpw8c2v1cewZQiHY65WGswtCP@QxDHXiGTmkhJSpFuUXNBKPYI/ObW1E/WMSyYMLsknIBHGLYKvgA9gW2Dg2SreloWFJzBckIUthAAmtYjcgGLMm1dn3xkLkdlP5j/gutLKZ0dziCjmvccndAut6NoifQR7xMVuLl3s9N07wB)

Function `#` builds a list of all possible splits by looking at both

- prepending the current number `a` to all splits returned by a recursive call with the rest of the input (`x<-b#c`), but only if the next number not zero (`b>0`) (or it's the last number in the input (`c==[]`)) and `a` is one greater than the first number of the respective previous split `x` (`a==x!!0+1`).

and

- appending the next digit `b` from the input list to the current number `a` and going on with the rest of the input (`(10*a+b)#c`)

Base case is when the input list is empty (i.e. does not pattern match `(b:c)`). The recursion starts with the current number `a` being `0` (`(0#)`), which never hits the first branch (prepending `a` to all previous splits), because it will never be greater than any number of the splits.

Take the length of each split and find the maximum (`maximum.map length`).

A variant with also 87 bytes:

```
fst.maximum.(0#)
a#(b:c)=[(r+1,a)|c==[]||b>0,(r,x)<-b#c,a==x+1]++(10*a+b)#c
a#b=[(1,a)]
```

which basically works the same way, but instead of keeping the whole split in a list, it only keeps a pair `(r,x)` of the length of the split `r` an the first number in the split `x`.

Answer (score 3):

## Dyalog APL, 138 bytes

Bit of a mouthful, but it works fast for big numbers too. If you [try it online](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1Hf1EdtE6of9XToP@rdqqHxqHPRo64mzcPTDR91LNezNdLVNzR41LX00AqQ6KPeFY96lxg@6lpkqFP9qHfNo86Fho/aJgM1Wj1qmwgUMHzU3WJg@6irGSRkoPOoox0qDxQHqtAxUAAaO0NPB2gY2CC4fC2MVjBSACpSsPz/HwA), prefix the dfn by `⎕←` and provide input on the right as a list of digits.

```
{⌈/⍵((≢⊂)×1∧.=2-/10⊥¨⊂)⍨⍤1⊢1,{⍬≡1↓⍵:↑⍬1⋄0=⊃⍵:0,∇1↓⍵⋄↑,0 1∘.,⊂⍤1∇1↓⍵}1↓⍵}
```

#### Explanation

First, the inner dfn on the right which recursively constructs a list of possible ways to partition (with `⊂`) the list of digits. For example `1 0 1 0 ⊂ 2 0 1 9` returns the nested vector `(2 0)(1 9)`.

```
{
   ⍬≡1↓⍵: ↑⍬1       ⍝ Edge case: If ⍵ is singleton list, return the column matrix (0 1)
   0=⊃⍵: 0,∇1↓⍵     ⍝ If head of ⍵ is 0, return 0 catenated to this dfn called on tail ⍵
   ↑,0 1∘.,⊂⍤1∇1↓⍵  ⍝ Finds 1 cat recursive call on tail ⍵ and 0 cat recursive call on ⍵. 
}                    ⍝ Makes a matrix with a row for each possibility.
```

We use `1,` to add a column of 1s at the start and end up with a matrix of valid partitions for ⍵.

Now the function train on the left in parens. Due to `⍨` the left argument to the train is the row of the partitions matrix and the right argument is the user input.
The train is a pile of forks with an atop as the far left tine.

```
((≢⊂)×1∧.=2-/10⊥¨⊂)⍨     ⍝ ⍨ swaps left and right arguments of the train.
                  ⊂       ⍝ Partition ⍵ according to ⍺. 
             10⊥¨         ⍝ Decode each partition (turns strings of digits into numbers)
          2-/             ⍝ Difference between adjacent cells
      1∧.=                ⍝ All equal 1?
   ⊂                      ⍝ Partition ⍵ according to ⍺ again
  ≢                       ⍝ Number of cells (ie number of partitions)
     ×                    ⍝ Multiply.
```

If the partition creates a sequence of descending numbers, the train returns the length of the sequence. Otherwise zero.

`⍤1⊢` applies the function train between the user input and each row of the partitions matrix, returning a value for each row of the matrix. `⊢` is necessary to disambiguate between operand to `⍤` and argument to the derived function of `⍤`.

`⌈/` finds the maximum.

Could find a shorter algorithm but I wanted to try this way which is the most direct and declarative I could think of.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! This is an impressive first post!

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 65 bytes

```
f i=[y|x<-[0..],y<-[1..length i],i==(show=<<[x+y-1,x+y-2..x])]!!0
```

Input is a string.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY09DoMwDEb3niJlAjVEdviNRI7QE0QZGKBEBYoKUkHq3VOiDokHy@99tjy067MbR2t7YqQ6vnuTKmBM0@MckLGxmx/bQIymRsp4HV4f2TRqvx0pUtc5Y7tO9PUKdmrNTCSZ2uVO4uVt5o2RPrkQVyrigCKifyKOOJxGoKi9zXheeqqrssg9Is/yIogRQIjw2gkIGRFEXQVPEYLUj4HNkAcrAiNtfw)

Completely different to my [other answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/178425/34531). A simple brute force that tries all lists of consecutive descending numbers until it finds one that equals the input list.

If we limit the input number to 64-bit integers, we can save 6 bytes by looping `y` through `[1..19]`, because the largest 64-bit integer has 19 digits and there's no need to test lists with more elements.

#### Haskell, 59 bytes

```
f i=[y|x<-[0..],y<-[1..19],i==(show=<<[x+y-1,x+y-2..x])]!!0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3PCoMwDIfve4rqSVktSf0bsI@wJyg9eJgoUydzMIW9e2fZoc0h5Pt@CRm67XGfJmt7Nip9fPc20yCE4cc5oBBIho9KJdvw/Ki21fv1yJC7LoXYTWqiCOzcjQtTbO7WG0vW17i8BevTC3OlYwlIMf8TcyThNITUeJvLovLU1FVZeESZF2UQIwBReO0EhIwI1NTBU4Qg9WNgc5TBCmFs7A8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 95 bytes

```python
lambda n:max(j-i for j in range(n+1)for i in range(-1,j)if''.join(map(str,range(j,i,-1)))==`n`)
```

Another slow, brute-force solution.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYsxDsIwEARreMU2kX3ijHCoiBReQhGjYDiLXCKTAl5vElHQrFYzmukzP0atS0SLS3mG4doHaDOEt01OEMeMBFHkoPeb1Z2nFckfOc@JJBqzT6OoHcJkX3Pmn0ws7DwRtW2nHZW11bWt/YHhGcsefb3ck2@2mymLzjDVsYc7o@oNKlhlRKtE5Qs)

Answer (score 1):

## TSQL, 169 bytes

Note: this can only be executed when the input can be converted to an integer.

Recursive sql used for looping.

Golfed:

```
DECLARE @ varchar(max) = '1211109876';

WITH C as(SELECT left(@,row_number()over(order by 1/0))+0t,@+null z,0i
FROM spt_values UNION ALL
SELECT t-1,concat(z,t),i+1FROM C WHERE i<9)SELECT
max(i)FROM C WHERE z=@
```

Ungolfed:

```
DECLARE @ varchar(max) = '1211109876';

WITH C as
(
  SELECT
    left(@,row_number()over(order by 1/0))+0t,
    @+null z,
    0i
  FROM
    spt_values
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    t-1,
    concat(z,t),
    i+1
  FROM C
  WHERE i<9
)
SELECT max(i)
FROM C
WHERE z=@
```

**[Try it out](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/962931/how-many-consecutive-descending-numbers-in-my-number)**

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 101 bytes

```r
function(a,N=nchar(a)){for(x in 1:N)F=max(F,which(Reduce(paste0,seq(substr(a,1,x),,-1,N),a=T)==a));F}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fdHLaoQwFAbgfZ8i0IUJHCEn3pIpdunSRekLWKvoYnTqhQqlz26PM7XO2NFANge@/PmTZszDMe@rtCvriicQh1VaJA1PhPjK64YPrKwYHmIRhcdk4BF8FmVa8JfsvU8zfkraLpPQZh@87d/ajhwgDALARogFJOGrCEM66yn6HnNuKYnGYr9LMPZo289MSUDDljXN6r479R07MPVwYUoSNWi0tTAEmpI1tPUtcyfmKNf/lzYN2VYaTkwHvudaK6YhAB88cO8xb2KoHNeb82Z2Ge6loZTGUK1bRr2oFrW6w5yZSb1OOw930xCl0cEqDQEpD6jjRjeF8u8hl3@jr5ZbL3m@5BVa2DXZuOQ9hrts/AE)

More than 2 weeks have passed without any R answer, so I decided to post my own :)

The code is pretty fast since it uses a "limited" brute force approach

#### Unrolled code and explanation :

```r
function(a){                  # get string a as input (e.g. "2019")

  N = nchar(a)                # set N = length of a (e.g. 4)
  Y = 0                       # initialize Y = 0 (in the actual code we abuse F)

  for(x in 1:N){              # for x in 1 ... N    

    S = substr(a,1,x)         # get the first x characters of a (e.g. "20" for x=2)

    Q = seq(S,,-1,N)          # create a decreasing sequence (step = -1) 
                              # of length N starting from S converted into integer
                              # (e.g. Q = c(20,19,18,17) for x=2)

    R = Reduce(paste0,Q,a=T)  # concatenate all the increasing sub-sequences of Q
                              # (e.g. R = c("20","2019","201918","20191817") for x=2)

    I = which(R == a)         # Get the index where R == a, if none return empty vector
                              # (e.g. I = 2 for x=2)

    Y = max(Y,I)              # store the maximum index found into Y
  }
  return(Y)                   # return Y
}
```